# Do iterators have conciousness of their position?

Tags: c++

Say I have a map where the key is an `int` for the sake of simplicity and to be able to reproduce the issue with a minimal compiling example. In my own case, the key is a much more complex beast.

I would like to reuse this map in order to create another map, with a different key: say an `enum` instead of an `int`. For this I have two functions that allow me to transform an `int` into the `enum`, and vice versa.

Rather than rewriting the whole class, I use composition and I put my map (in this case a `map<int,int>` Inside my new class myMap.

I started with the following implementation, but I have an issue with the custom iterator in my class A. I have not chosen to inherit from `std::iterator`, nor from `map<int,int>::iterator` but use composition again instead:

```
class myMap
{
private:
    std::map<int, int> m;

public:

    typedef std::map<int, int> map_type;
    typedef enum { X1=0, X2, X3, INVALID } key_type;
    typedef int mapped_type;
    typedef pair<key_type, mapped_type> value_type;

    /* conversions from int to key_type and vice versa */
    friend key_type int2K(int k);
    friend int K2int(key_type k);

    class Iterator
    {
    private:
        map_type::iterator it;
        key_type K;
    public:

        Iterator(map_type::iterator & i) : 
                 it(i), K(int2K(i->first)) {} //<= Error if i is not valid (points to the end)
    };

    typedef Iterator iterator;

    iterator end() { return iterator(m.end()); }
    // other parts of the class skipped for concisness  
};

myMap::key_type int2K(int k) {
    return (k == 0 ? myMap::X1 : 
           (k == 1 ? myMap::X2 : 
           (k == 3 ? myMap::X3 : 
                  myMap::INVALID))); }

int K2int(myMap::key_type k) { return k; }
```

When I initialize an iterator of myMap to the end of the map, it fails:

```
myMap m;
myMap::iterator i = m.end(); //<= fails here
```

Is there any way to check in my constructor whether the iterator points to the end of the map or not ? If so how ?

Comment: You can to the convertion only when deferencing the `Iterator`.

Comment: check out iterator_facade in boost

Comment: @sp2danny I know iterator_facade, but it is not going to solve my issue. My problem is not to know what interface an iterator needs to fulfill, it is more a design issue in my iterator class.

Comment: You can't know if it is an end iterator without context. The context is only available at the call side of the iterator constructor, so you could add an additional flag parameter to the constructor to tell it that the given iterator is an end iterator.

Comment: I think in this case you are better of with key conversion functions, and to just use the old map

Comment: @zett42 "the context is only available at the call side of the iterator constructor": this is my question actually. Is there a way for an iterator to know its position (past the end) without a reference to the container it is iterating through ?

Comment: @Jarod42 what conversion are you refering to ?

Comment: @Heyji In general it depends on implementation. If the iterator defines "past the end" by using a constant sentinel value or flag, it would be able to know that it is "past the end" even without a container (e. g. `std::directory_iterator` is implemented like this).

Comment: @zett43: what about a test like `if it++==it` to check whether one is past the end

Comment: I meant, don't store `key_type K`, reimplement method for Iterator, in particular, `std::pair<const key_type, int> operator*() const { return {int2K(it->first), it->second}; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. As said by zett42 in the comment of the question, the only place where the position of the iterator is known, is at the iterator call side.

To solve the issue though, as Jarod42 suggests, a solution can be found by computing the equivalent key `K` only when dereferencing the iterator:

```
Iterator(map_type::iterator & i): it(i) {};

value_type operator*() {
    return { int2K(it->first), it->second};
}
```

**Note:** in a former answer, I tried to test whether an iterator is at the end of its container by copying it, incrementing the copy by one, and checking whether the copy still equals the original pointer (pointed to the end).

But as zett42 pointed out, this does not work: 
- incrementing an iterator pointing to the end of a container should be undefined behavior
- Even a simple pointer qualifies as an iterator. In this case it is trivial to see that this solution does not work.

```
/* DISCLAIMER: Not working ! */
Iterator(map_type::iterator & i) : it(i), K(INVALID) 
{
    map_type::iterator j = i;
    j++;
    if(i!=j) K = int2K(i->first);
}
```

Comment: [Doesn't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27b9c61bec8ecd55). And how do you even think this should work? An iterator is not required to hold any information about the container, even a regular pointer qualifies as an iterator.

Comment: @zett42: thank you for your comment. I have updated the answer, you might want to update your comment as well (and your vote :-)